# Retorno de objetos select (ComboBox) com Hibernate + JSP + VRaptor. Não preenche relacionamento entre tabelas

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, vraptor

Tenho um objeto `TabelaPrecoItem` com todas a estrutura formada e quase tudo funcionando,
segue o modelo do model.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "fov_tabela_preco_itens")
    public class TabelaPrecoItem implements Serializable {


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7517120126809692389L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    //    @Column(name = "tab_id")
    //    private Integer tab_id;

    //    @Column(name = "pro_id")
    //    private Integer id_produto;

    @Column(name = "tpi_preco")
    private Double preco;

    @Column(name = "tpi_minimo")
    private Double minimo;

    @Column(name = "tpi_maximo")
    private Double maximo;

    @NotNull(message = "Campo \"Tabela de Preço\" precisa ser informado.")
    @JoinColumn(name = "tab_id")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = TabelaPreco.class)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION)
    private TabelaPreco tabelaPreco;

    @NotNull(message = "Campo \"Produto\" precisa ser informado.")
    @JoinColumn(name = "pro_id")
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Produto.class)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.EXCEPTION)
    private Produto produto;
```

Basicamente tudo está funcionando. O método do `controler` que seleciona está retornando todos os objetos corretamente, estou com problemas é quando eu tento editar esse objeto.

Criei o JSP da seguinte forma

```
<div id="msgErroModal" class="alert alert-danger fade"
    style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></div>
<form id="formCadastro" method="post"  accept-charset="UTF-8" class="smart-form" onsubmit='<c:if test="${acao != \"exibir\"}">submitForm("tabelaprecoitem", "formCadastro");</c:if> return false;' action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <section>
            <div class="inline-group">
            <div class="col col-3"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
            <section>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="label col col-3 text-right"><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> Tabela de PreÃ§o</label>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <label class="select">
                        <select name="tabelaPrecoItem.tabelaPreco.id" required  disabled="disabled">
                            <option value="">Selecione uma Tabela</option>
                            <c:forEach var="tabela" items="${tabelaPrecoList}">
                                <option value="${tabela.id}" <c:if test="${tabela.id eq tabelaPrecoItem.tabelaPreco.id}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${tabela.descricao}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select >
                        <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>    

        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="label col col-3 text-right">ID</label>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <label class="input"><i></i>
                        <input type="text" value="${tabelaPrecoItem.id}" disabled="disabled">
                        <input type="hidden" name="tabelaPrecoItem.id" value="${tabelaPrecoItem.id}">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>        
            <section>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="label col col-3 text-right"><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> Produto</label>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <label class="select">
                        <select name="tabelaPrecoItem.produto.id" required  disabled="disabled">
                            <option value="">Selecione um Produto</option>
                            <c:forEach var="produto" items="${produtoList}">
                                <option value="${produto.id}" <c:if test="${produto.id eq tabelaPrecoItem.produto.id}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${produto.descricao}</option>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </select >
                        <i class="fa fa-group"></i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>    
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="label col col-3 text-right"><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> PreÃ§o</label>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <label class="input">
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Ex: 20" name="tabelaPrecoItem.preco" value="${tabelaPrecoItem.preco}" required>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="label col col-3 text-right"><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> MÃ­nimo</label>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <label class="input">
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Ex: 20" name="tabelaPrecoItem.minimo" value="${tabelaPrecoItem.minimo}" >
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="row">
                <label class="label col col-3 text-right"><i class="fa fa-asterisk text-danger"></i> MÃ¡ximo</label>
                <div class="col col-9">
                    <label class="input">
                        <input type="number" step="0.01" placeholder="Ex: 20" name="tabelaPrecoItem.maximo" value="${tabelaPrecoItem.maximo}">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

    </fieldset>

    <footer>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-danger pull-left">
            <i class="fa fa-asterisk"> Campo(s) ObrigatÃ³rio(s).</i>
        </div>
        <c:if test="${acao != \"exibir\"}">
            <button id="salvarModal" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Salvar</button>
        </c:if>
        <button id="fecharModal" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Fechar</button>
    </footer>
</form>
```

Quando eu preencho os objetos com o método

```
    @Get("/{id}/editarproduto")
    public void editar(Integer id) {
        TabelaPrecoItem TabelaPrecoItemAux = null;

        try {
            TabelaPrecoItemAux = this.repository.loadById(id);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.showErrorViewExceptionValidator(e,
                    "Falha ao carregar dados do Item da Tabela de Preços id " + id
                            + ", por favor tente novamente!", "TabelaPrecoItem");
        }

        this.result.include("acao", "editar").
        include("tabelaPrecoItem", TabelaPrecoItemAux).
        include("tabelaPrecoList",this.tabelaPrecoRepository.loadAll()).
        include("produtoList",this.produtoRepository.loadAll()).
        forwardTo(this).cadastroProduto();
    }
```

A tela é preenchida de forma correta. Mas quando eu chamo o método de edição, para gravar as alterações no banco de dados, os objetos de `tabelaPrecoItem.produto` e `tabelaPrecoItem.tabelaPreco` estão retornando como `null`.

```
@Post("")
    public void salvar(TabelaPrecoItem tabelaPrecoItem) {
        String message = "";
        try {
            // Realiza a validaçãoo Server-Side
            this.validator.validate(tabelaPrecoItem);

            // Verifica erros e retorna para camada de visão, caso contrario
            // segue o fluxo normal de cadastro
            if (this.validator.getErrors().size() == 0) {

                if (tabelaPrecoItem.getId() == 0) {
                    tabelaPrecoItem = repository.add(tabelaPrecoItem);
                    message = "Novo Produto da Tabela de Preços id " + tabelaPrecoItem.getId()
                            + " cadastrado com sucesso!";

                } else {
                    tabelaPrecoItem = repository.update(tabelaPrecoItem);
                    message = "Produto da Tabela de Preços id " + tabelaPrecoItem.getId()
                            + " alterado com sucesso!";
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.showErrorViewExceptionValidator(
                    e,
                    "Falha ao tentar salvar dados do Produto da Tabela de Preços, por favor tente novamente!",
                    "TabelaPreco");
        }

        // retorna o objeto de retorno fora do try catch para evitar exception
        // desnecessárias
        if (!message.equals("")) {
            result.use(Results.json()).withoutRoot().from(message).serialize();

        } else {
            this.returnErrorValidatorMessage();
        }
    }
```

E com isso não passa no `validate`.

Answer (score 1):

na hora de carregar sua entidade ele não esta carregando as entidades relacionadas, você pode conseguir isso usando "cascade" que é um atributo das anotações de relacionamento como por exemplo:

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

isso faz com que qualquer operação na entidade seja reproduzida nas entidades relacionadas,

mas você pode limitar isso para uma unica operação com os outros tipos de Cascade: PERSISTE,MERGE,REMOVE, REFRESH

Comment: Coloquei a anotação no model `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = Produto.class) ` e `@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = TabelaPreco.class)` mesmo assim no retorno do objeto do JSP para a classe ele ainda está vindo como null `"tabelaPrecoItem"  (pending) 
 id 1 
 maximo Double  (id=133) 
 minimo Double  (id=137) 
 preco Double  (id=138) 
 produto null 
 tabelaPreco null 
` acho que os selects (Combobox) do JSP não estão preenchendo os objetos. Pode ser algum erro no name deles ?

Answer (score 0):

O `comboBox` na tela estava como `Disabled`, por esse motivo o `Vraptor` não identifica o objeto.
Para solucionar eu habilitei o `combobox` antes do post e desabilitei novamente após o post.